# Rest web services using Jersey 2.26

Tags: java, rest, tomcat

I am using Apache Tomcat 9 and trying to implement a basic rest service.
My web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Test</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My rest service class is

```
@Path("/service")
public class RestService {

    @GET
    @Path("/first")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String generateResponse() {


        return "abc";
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/login")
    public String returnJSON(String userData)
    {

        JSONObject returnObject=new JSONObject();
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {
            JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(userData);
            final String username = (String) json.get("username");
            final String password = (String) json.get("password");
            returnObject.put("username", username);
            returnObject.put("password", password);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }





        return returnObject.toString();
    }
}
```

The included jars in lib folder
[image: Jars]

However, when I call the webservice by hitting http://localhost:8080/Test/resources, it gives an error

Type Exception Report

Message Servlet.init() for servlet [javax.ws.rs.core.Application] threw exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [javax.ws.rs.core.Application] threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:409)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

How to fix this?